# Make a channel private

Tags: channel

Is it possible in out of the box Expression Engine to make a channel private and viewable only by the administrators member group?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Two parts to this - not clear from your posting.

To make a channel that only a private group can access from the control panel:

- First create the channel you want to make private.  Then click on the Members button and work through the member groups that you do not wish to be able to have access to the channel and de-select it from the "Allowed Channels" selector (which is the last one as you scroll down).
- Second, head over to the group(s) you do want to have access and just check that the channel is selected for those groups.

To make a channel only visible to users from a particular group in your public site, add this kind of conditional to your template:

```
{if logged_in_group_id == "xxx"}
... template tags to show channel to your group with group ID xxx
{/if}
```

That's it.  Easy!

HTH

Comment: I think the Allowed Channels applies only the Allowed Actions. I don't have any of the channels selected for the Guest group and guests can still see all the channels.

Comment: Well it works here ... I created a member group for an EE 5.2.3 installation, and then only gave it permission to access two channels.  When I log in as a member of that group EE CP only shows those two channels in the Channels drop-down.  If you have done this (i.e. limit a member group to specific channels) and still they can see the channels you have excluded from their access, sounds like a bug...